# Prove $a(n, k) = t(n, k + 1)$ with permutations and cycles where 1 and 2 are/are not in the same cycle?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, permutation-cycles

Let $a(n, k)$ be the number of permutations of length n with k cycles in which the entries 1 and 2 are
in the same cycle. Let $t(n, k) = c(n, k) − a(n, k)$ be the number of permutations of length
n with k cycles in which the entries 1 and 2 are not in the same cycle. Prove that $a(n, k) = t(n, k + 1)$
for all $k ≤ n − 1.$

EDIT: I've tried directly summing the generating functions for (,),(,), and we got $x^2(+1)...(+−1)$, but we don't know where to go from there. We also tried using the fact that $t(n, k) = c(n, k) − a(n, k)$ to perhaps get some sort of relation that makes more sense, but the only relations that we can make rely on using the fact we're trying to prove, which is sort of counterproductive.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried directly summing the generating functions for $c(n,k), a(n,k)$, and we got $x^2(x+1)...(x+n-1)$, but we don't know where to go from there. We also tried using the fact that $t(n,k) = c(n,k) - a(n,k)$ to perhaps get some sort of relation that makes more sense, but the only relations that we can make rely on using the fact we're trying to prove, which is sort of counterproductive.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $\sigma$ be one of the permutations counted by $a(n,k),$ then $$\sigma = (1\, a_1\, \cdots\, a_i\, 2\, b_1\, \cdots \, b_j)c_2\cdots c_k,$$ where $c_i$ are cycles and $\{a_m,b_m\}$ are numbers. What if you define a function
$$\varphi (\sigma )=(1\, a_1\, \cdots\, a_i)(2\, b_1\, \cdots \, b_j)c_2\cdots c_k.$$
Is this a bijection?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to the notation you're using in the first line. What do the $a_i, b_i$ represent?

Comment: @DrewWeisserman The a and b are numbers. So, for example take the permutation $634125,$ this can be written in cycle form as $(165234),$ so the $a_i$ are 6 and 5 and the $b_i$ are 3,4.<br> Also, $\varphi (\, (165234) \,)=(165)(234).$

Comment: Oh, I see! So if you just create a bijection between the cycle where 1 and 2 are together, and split the cycle up at wherever 2 is (assuming we define 1 to be the start of the cycle), we have a bijection! That makes sense, thank you so much!

Comment: wait, how would we be able to add the (k+1) element of $t(n, k+1)$? This feels like it would show a relation between $a(n,k)$ and $t(n,k)$.

Comment: @DrewWeisserman But if you split $1$ cycle into $2$ cycles, then you are increasing the number of cycles by $1$